# How do we loop over the individual form controls in a form group?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using Reactive forms in Angular and have a formGroup object which looks as below:

```
form = this.fb.group({
  Basic: this.fb.group ({
    net1: '',
    net2: ''
  }),
  Advanced: this.fb.group ({
    Area1: this.fb.group ({ 
      key1: 'test',
      key2: 'pass'
    }),
    Area2: this.fb.group ({
      key3: ''
  })
})
```

The formgroup object is dynamic and the name of the keys here may change (based on the server response). How do I render these formcontrols (net1, net2, key1, key2...) in my HTML template?

I am not sure how do I parse them in the HTML?

The HTML I am using now looks like:

```
<div>
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form">
  <div formGroupName="Basic">
    <h1>{{key}}</h1>
    <input type="textbox" formControlName="net1">
    <input type="textbox" formControlName="net2">
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Save</button>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

For now I have hard coded the formControlName here but I wish to loop over all the controls in my HTML. I know we can loop over this if this was FormArray but since it is not, how do I proceed?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: https://ng-run.com/edit/LFvdYySoD2OJee4h3kZ3

Comment: Thanks @yurzui... What if I have the formgroup names inside the Advanced as variables as well? How do we cater to that? Say, the Area1 and Area2 are not constants

Comment: Updated example. As you can see you can build any structure dynamically.

Comment: Thanks much @yurzui

Comment: @yurzui When I use the template HTML you gave, it displays a single input box with all the formcontrol values of the basic section appended in the box.

Comment: Can you reproduce it on stackblitz? Maybe you need to add `div` blocks somewhere

Comment: @yurzui Oh yes! Got the issue. Thanks

Comment: @yurzui can you help me out with the extention to the same question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50773488/how-to-parse-json-values-to-be-fed-to-formcontrol