# How to parse JSON values to be fed to formcontrol?

Tags: json, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I get JSON reponse from the server from which I take the metadata required to build the FormGroup object. Since the JSON is dynamic and so is FormGroup object, how to parse the JSON fields in HTML?

I looked at the angular documentation for dynamic forms https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form but here I see they are passing each class object to the **dynamic-form-question.component.ts** from the parent **dynamic-form.component.ts**

My JSON:

```
[
  {
    "key": "Basic",
    "required": false,
    "controlType": "section",
    "children": [
        {
            "key": "net1",
            "required": false,
            "controlType": "dropdown"
        },
        {
            "default": "",
            "key": "net2",
            "required": true,
            "controlType": "textbox"
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Advanced",
    "required": false,
    "controlType": "section",
    "children": [
        {
            "key": "Area1",
            "required": false,
            "controlType": "sub-section",
            "children": [
                {
                    "default": "test",
                    "key": "key1",
                    "required": false,
                    "controlType": "dropdown",
                    "choices" : [ "test",
                                  "test1",
                                  "test2"
                                ]
                },
                {
                    "default": "pass",
                    "key": "key2",
                    "required": false,
                    "controlType": "textbox"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "Area2",
            "required": false,
            "controlType": "sub-section",
            "children": [
                {
                    "default": false,
                    "key": "key3",
                    "required": false,
                    "controlType": "radiobutton"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

for which the corresponding FormGroup Object is:

```
form = this.fb.group({
  Basic: this.fb.group ({
    net1: '',
    net2: ''
  }),
  Advanced: this.fb.group ({
    Area1: this.fb.group ({ 
      key1: 'test',
      key2: 'pass'
    }),
    Area2: this.fb.group ({
      key3: ''
  })
})
```

In the HTML I need to get the fields from the JSON like controlType to decide on the type of input element and also the choices in case of a dropdown.

What would be ideal way to parse the JSON in the typescript so that it can be passed onto the HTML?

Basically I want the child object eg,

```
{
    "key": "net1",
    "required": false,
    "controlType": "dropdown"
}
```

to be passed to JSON along with the corresponding formGroup object.

My HTML looks like:

```
<div>
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form">
    <div formGroupName="Basic">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let controlName of controls('Basic.children')" formGroupName="children">
        <input type="textbox" [formControlName]="controlName"><br>
      </ng-container>
    </div>

    <div formGroupName="Advanced">
      <div *ngFor="let groupName of controls('Advanced')" [formGroupName]="groupName">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let controlName of controls('Advanced.' + groupName)">
          <input type="textbox" [formControlName]="controlName"><br>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Save</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

so that I can apply ngSwitch on the controlType just like in the example on the official website. (As of now the input element is of one type only. ).

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

I just did a solution, there might be a few things wrong with it, and it is not that dynamic, but it could still help

this is my template:

```
<form novalidate >
    <div *ngFor="let input of inputs">
        <input [type]="input">
    </div>
</form>
```

i completely copied your JSON Example and used that to model my solution

this is the component.ts

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  inputs: Array<String> = [];

  jsonExample: Object;


  constructor() { 


  }

  ngOnInit() {

this.jsonExample = 
[
  {
    "key": "Basic",
    "required": false,
    "controlType": "section",
    "children": [
        {
            "key": "net1",
            "required": false,
            "controlType": "dropdown"
        },
        {
            "default": "",
            "key": "net2",
            "required": true,
            "controlType": "textbox"
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Advanced",
    "required": false,
    "controlType": "section",
    "children": [
        {
            "key": "Area1",
            "required": false,
            "controlType": "sub-section",
            "children": [
                {
                    "default": "test",
                    "key": "key1",
                    "required": false,
                    "controlType": "dropdown",
                    "choices" : [ "test",
                                  "test1",
                                  "test2"
                                ]
                },
                {
                    "default": "pass",
                    "key": "key2",
                    "required": false,
                    "controlType": "textbox"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "Area2",
            "required": false,
            "controlType": "sub-section",
            "children": [
                {
                    "default": false,
                    "key": "key3",
                    "required": false,
                    "controlType": "radiobutton"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  }
];

this.parseJSON();



}

  parseJSON() {

    Object.keys(this.jsonExample).forEach(key => {
      Object.keys(this.jsonExample[key]['children']).forEach(key2 => {
        if (this.jsonExample[key]['children'][key2]['controlType'] ===  'sub-section') {
          Object.keys(this.jsonExample[key]['children'][key2]['children']).forEach(key3 => {
            this.inputs.push(this.jsonExample[key]['children'][key2]['children'][key3]['controlType']);
          });
        }
        else {
          this.inputs.push(this.jsonExample[key]['children'][key2]['controlType']);
        }
      });
    });

  }

}
```

so basically I am checking for every controlType key and then adding the value of it to an array, then using *ngFor  and data binding, not everything you wanted is in here, but you could do some changes to also get more values out of the object. I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Mannaroth. I'll try and see if this works out for me

Comment: @Mannorath It is not just about the controlType, I want the choices as well in case of dropdown. Basically, if the controlType is dropdown the <input [type]> would not be correct, as I would want it to be of type <select>

Comment: ok, do you use names for your radiobuttons? or how do you setup a radio group

Comment: Yes I use name for my radio buttons whatever I get from JSON key.